# move div down below fixed header

Tags: html, css

i have searched about and can't seem to find the answer I am looking for.

I want to know how to move my div down below my fixed header.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    background: #6396bc;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 15%
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif
}

.nav {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>team Zeus | Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1><a href="#">team Zeus</a></h1>
                </div>
                
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1 other page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
        
        <div class="content">
            <p>I copied and pasted some article from Wikipedia in here, you could do that too (to test out the header at the top)</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think it is something to do with the containers, because when I try and resize them with width, it just messes the full page around. I cannot figure it out

Thanks

Comment: When you run it, you cannot see any text from the paragraph... because it is hidden behind the header.

Comment: Try adding margin-top: 5em (or however much you need) to your . content rules. The header is fixed so its not in the document flow and the content doesn't know how to flow around so you have to add styles to make room

Comment: Remove that second container classed div and add to the content class div `margin: 200px auto 0px auto ;` adjust the 200px to fit your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean just move the content down below the header? If that's what you want just position the content div like this:

```
.div {
      position:relative;
      top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you - I will make it the answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will definately help

[image]

Comment: When I done that, in Brackets, it just made the header even bigger (vertically). Do you know why this happened?